# if bottom sheet open that time how to move back screen container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-container

When double tap on image container that time open bottom sheet model and alternative container is show.

when bottom sheet open that time my alternative container show but i have to move this alternative container also how to move using gesture to alternative container.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MovableImageBox extends StatefulWidget {
  late final _MovableImageBoxState currentWidget;
  int index;

  MovableImageBox({required this.index});

  @override
  _MovableImageBoxState createState() {
    _MovableImageBoxState currentState = _MovableImageBoxState();
    this.currentWidget = currentState;
    return currentWidget;
  }
}

const ballDiameter = 15.0;
const rotateIconSize = 30.0;

class _MovableImageBoxState extends State<MovableImageBox> {
  double width = 300;
  double height = 200.0;
  double aspectRatio = 200 / 300;
  bool _isSelected = true;
  double top = 100;
  double left = 100;
  bool _showAlternateContainer = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [

      Positioned(
        top: top,
        left: left,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            for (var i = 0; i < GlobalState.movableAllWidgets.length; i++) {
              print("_addMovableTextBox $i");
              GlobalState.movableAllWidgets[i].currentWidget
                  .updateIsSelected(false);
            }
            setState(() {
              _isSelected = true;
              GlobalState.selectedIndex = widget.index;
              print("index = ${GlobalState.selectedIndex}");
            });
          },
          onPanDown: (details) {
            print("down time width =$width");
            print("down time height =$height");
            for (var i = 0; i < GlobalState.movableAllWidgets.length; i++) {
              print("_addMovableTextBox $i");
              GlobalState.movableAllWidgets[i].currentWidget
                  .updateIsSelected(false);
            }
            setState(() {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              _isSelected = true;
            });
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              top += details.delta.dy;
              left += details.delta.dx;
            });
          },
          onDoubleTap: () {
            _showBottomSheet();
            _showAlternateContainer = true;
          },
          child: Container(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            decoration:
            BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              border: Border.all(
                width: 2,
                color: _isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),

            child: ClipRect(
              child: Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'images/rose1.png',
                  width: width,
                  height: height,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // ),
        ),
      ),

      if ( _showAlternateContainer)
        Positioned(
          top: top,
          left: left,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              if (!_showAlternateContainer) {
                setState(() {
                  top += details.delta.dy;
                  left += details.delta.dx;
                  print("container  move");
                });
              }
            },

            child: Container(
                height: height - 20,
                width: width - 20,
                // color: Colors.transparent,
              decoration:
              BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 2,
                  color: _isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Alternate Container',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ),
        ),
           

  void _showBottomSheet() {
    setState(() {
      GlobalState.isBottomSheetVisible.value = true;
      _showAlternateContainer = true;
    });
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withAlpha(50),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 230,
          child: Center(
            child: Text("This is a bottom sheet"),
          ),
        );
      },
    ).whenComplete(() {
      print("${GlobalState.isBottomSheetVisible}");
      setState(() {
        GlobalState.isBottomSheetVisible.value = false;
            _showAlternateContainer = false;

      });
      print("${GlobalState.isBottomSheetVisible}");
    });
  }
```

When double tap on image container that time open bottom sheet model and alternative container is show.

when bottom sheet open that time my alternative container show but i have to move this alternative container also how to move using gesture to alternative container.

[image]

Comment: you have to Use Stack instead of bottomShet

Comment: but when double tap on container that time i have to open bottom sheet.

Comment: You can change the stack position and make it appears in the bottom